# Whitespaces between URLs and punctuation on stackoverflow.co pages

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, whitespace, stackoverflow.co

I couldn't help but notice some URLs have whitespaces between the punctuation that follows them in various stackoverflow.co subpages. For example, not using a `&nbsp` in the [*Media kit*](https://stackoverflow.co/company/press) page, as shown in the below screenshot, has the new line starting with a comma:

[image: Media kit page]

The same happens on the [*Contact us* page](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/), the [*Research* page](https://stackoverflow.co/company/research/) and the middle icon at the bottom of the [*About* page](https://stackoverflow.co/).

[image: About page]

Comment: Note that https://stackoverflow.co/ is not the same thing as [The Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/), which is the name of the blog and podcast.

Comment: @V2Blast you're right, I was confused about how to tag this. Since [stackoverflow.co](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962) can be considered its own subject going forward I created a new tag.